# Swift: Filter a NSSet for class types

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsset

In objective-C I had this function to filter an `NSSet` for an array of class types:

```
+ (NSSet *)filterSubjectsSet:(NSSet *)subjects forClasses:(NSArray *)classes
{
    NSSet *filterSet = [subjects objectsPassingTest:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        return [classes containsObject:[obj class]];
    }];
    return filterSet;
}
```

I am struggling to find a neat way to implement the same function in Swift. This is what I had hoped would work:

```
class func filterSubjectsSet(subjects: NSSet, forClasses classes: [AnyClass]) -> NSSet {

    let set = subjects.objectsPassingTest() {
        find(classes, object_getClass($0)) != nil
    }        
    return set
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Type 'AnyObject.Type' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: shouldn't you be testing whether an object is an instance of a class (or subclasses thereof), rather than that its class is exactly that class?

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` function is specified as:

```
func find<C : Collection where C.GeneratorType.Element : Equatable>
   (domain: C, value: C.GeneratorType.Element) -> C.IndexType?
```

and thus the collection, `classes` in your case, must be `Equatable`.  Apparently a class type is not equatable - hence the error.  I'd just loop over the classes 'by hand' as:

```
{
  let set = subjects.objectsPassingTest() {
    for class in classes {
      if class === object_getClass($0) {
        return true
      }
    return false
  }
  return set
}
```

Putting it all together into an example with a slight rewrite of the above body:

```
  1> import Cocoa 
  2. class Foo { init () {} } 
  3. class Bar : Foo { init () { super.init()} } 
  4. class Bing { init () {} } 
  5.  
  6. let b1 = Bing() 
  7. let b2 = Bing() 
  8.  
  9. var set1 = NSMutableSet() 
 10. set1.addObject(b1) 
 11. set1.addObject(b2) 
 12.  
 13. func filterSubjectsSet (subjects: NSSet, forClasses classes: [AnyClass]) -> NSSet { 
 14.   return subjects.objectsPassingTest() { 
 15.     (obj: AnyObject!, boolPtr: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) in 
 16.     for nextClass in classes { 
 17.       if nextClass === object_getClass(obj) { 
 18.         return true 
 19.       } 
 20.     } 
 21.     return false 
 22.   } 
 23. } 
 24.  
 25. set1.count 
 26.  
 27. filterSubjectsSet (set1, forClasses: [object_getClass(b1)]).count
$R0: Int = 2
b1: __lldb_expr_1.Bing = {}
b2: __lldb_expr_1.Bing = {}
set1: __NSSetM = 2 objects {
  [0] =
  [1] =
}
```

Comment: Thanks @GoZoner. Any idea why this call to the function fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION? `let filtered = Subject.filterSubjectsSet(places, forClasses: [Hospital.self])`

Comment: I am still getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, raised in `Foundation._convertArrayToNSArray <A>(Swift.Array<A>) -> ObjectiveC.NSArray`. This seems to be called when I pass my `forClasses` array parameter. I cannot see any difference in my code to your example above.